# A list comprehension with double elements

Tags: haskell

In Haskell if I write

```
[x/10 | x <- [1,3..10]]
```

I obtain

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `[1,3..10]` is wrong. Don't write that.

Comment: Why? What fixes that, i.e. to 0.9?

Comment: `[1,3..9]` of course.

Comment: But if you want `[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]` then just write `[0.1, 0.3..0.9]`. Maybe you've oversimplified your real question?

Comment: Yes, but if I do [1,3..10] in ghci it displays [1,3,5,7,9]

Comment: If I do that, the last term isn't exactly 0.9. It's 0.899999999999999

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to see this link.